# How can I get resharper to know that my variable is not null after I have called an extension method on it?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an extension method:

```
public static bool Exists(this object toCheck)
{
   return toCheck != null;
}
```

if I use it and then do something like this:

```
if (duplicate.Exists())
    throw new Exception(duplicate);
```

then resharper warns me that there is a possible null reference exception.

I know this is not possible, but how can I tell resharper that this is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with contract annotations, but the way provided in another answer does not work for me (that is - still produces a warning). But this one works:

```
public static class Extensions {
    [ContractAnnotation("null => false; notnull => true")]
    public static bool Exists(this object toCheck) {
        return toCheck != null;
    }
}
```

To get `ContractAnnotationAttribute` - recommended way is to install `JetBrains.Annotations` nuget package. If you don't want to install package - go to Resharper > Options > Code Annotations and press "copy implementation to clipboard" button, then paste it anywhere in your project (ensure to not change namespace).

Comment: Thanks. Can these annotations be applied without modifying the code or relying on using a resharper library? – Sam Holder just now   edit   
add a comment

Comment: Thanks! thats great

Comment: I've updated my answer with information about not using their nuget package. As for "without modifying source code" - not sure what you mean, you have to apply that attribute, so this part of source code should be modified (but seems not a problem). Source code that _uses_ this method should not be modified in any way though.

Comment: The old way of adding attributes supported doing it via an xml file (so you could add them to existing classes in libraries you don't own) so I wondered if the same thing was possible with this: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/11/17/resharper-nullreferenceexception-analysis-and-its-contracts/

Comment: This way is not old (I mean it is used up to this date), but usually for libraries where it is not possible to use regular attributes (like default .NET libraries). I think you should be able to do that with ContractAnnotation too if you'd like, though I must admit I did not test that. Since you own codebase - better just use regular attribute, because otherwise you will need to ship that annotations file with your library - and why bother with that?

Comment: Both adding the JetBrains.Annotations package and the attribute source code declare the attributes with the `[Conditional("JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS")]` attribute. This means that ReSharper can see them applied in source, but the compiler will only add them to your compiled output if your define the `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS` symbol. In other words, by default, the attributes are not embedded in your final assembly, and don't require redistribution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ["Contract Annotation Syntax"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html) to indicate to Resharper that a method does not return normally under some circumstances, e.g. when a parameter is null.

For your example you can do something like this:

```
[ContractAnnotation(toCheck:notnull => true]
public static bool Exists(this object toCheck)
{
   return toCheck != null;
}
```

Where the `toCheck:null => true` tells Resharper that if `toCheck` is not null, the method will return `true`.

[EDIT] Updated link to point to the most recent Resharper documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Can these annotations be applied without modifying the code or relying on using a resharper library?